# Google Cloud Firestore 'in' Operator Workaround

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using google cloud firestore as a database for a flutter application. My code requires that I make a request containing '.where("X", "in", "very-long-list")' to the database. The issue that arises is an 'in' operator can only combine up to 10 equality clauses while my list is of variable length that may end up significantly larger than 10. I am looking for possible workaround to the issue.

An example statement:

`citiesRef.where("state", "in", "[list-of-1000]");`

Edit: To give additional context, my project is a social media application where users have friends. The database is to being restructured such that a user document has a subcollection 'friends' with a document containing their user id. A user document also has a collection called posts with references to a chronologically ordered post collection. Within the posts collection, each post document has a document containing their UID. To create a user's feed, the post collection is to be referenced and filtered using '.where["UID", "in", ["List-of_friend-UIDs"])'. If you know of a better structure I am very open to restructuring my database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must use more than 10 items in an "in" query, then you will need to break it up into smaller lists of 10, perform 1 query for each batch of 10, and merge the results.

Comment: I have given more context in my post to better explain my project. The difficulty with this solution is that I intended on using a stream to get the post objects and having a batch of streams being merged could lead to ordering issues because the posts are ordered chronologically within the posts document.

Comment: My answer doesn't really change.  You will need to perform multiple queries.  You can sort the results afterward.

Comment: So does that mean I will need to fetch every post that fits the criteria (this may number in the thousands) then sort it on the client side? This is the only way? My concern with this method is it seems slow and resource intensive on the client side.

Comment: Unless you have another way of identifying each document in such a way that's compatible with Firestore's querying capabilities.  If you can't, then know that sorting 1000 things isn't going to take more than a couple milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you, this has been very informative. I will make my request and sort results upon widget build as opposed to using a stream